# What is wrong with this UNION statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am confussing a little bit and don't understand why I get this error.
So far I want to create `SEARCH` function in SQLDeveloper `PLSQL`
Since I have a multiple parameter to sent I use `UNION` but so far this doesn't work

```
FUNCTION SEARCH_CLIENT(name IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR 
     SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Name LIKE '%name%';
     UNION 
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Number LIKE '%name%'
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Company LIKE '%name%'
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Address LIKE '%name%'
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE CompanyId LIKE '%name%' 
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE InvoiceAddress LIKE '%name%'
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Worker_name LIKE '%name%'
     UNION
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE PostNumber LIKE '%name%';
RETURN rc;
END SEARCH_CLIENT;
```

I get errors like

```
Error(19,33): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

Error(17,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two obvious errors:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Name LIKE '%name%';    --> remove semi-colon
 UNION 
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Number LIKE '%name%'   --> number is invalid column name
```

---

A little bit less obvious: `LIKE` won't work. You'll have to use

```
WHERE Name LIKE '%' || name ||'%'
```

otherwise you'll search for strings that contain "name". Also, if column name is equal to parameter name, you'll get wrong result; change parameter name to e.g. `par_name` and then

```
WHERE Name LIKE '%' || par_name ||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION produces one result set from two subqueries. It is a single statement. So you need to remove the semi-colon from the first subquery preceding a UNION keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semicolon after your first union.

Other then that this is a terrible SQL statement, slow and inefficient.

Do a single select with multiple OR, do not use UNION

Comment: You mean insted of using UNION use OR statment 
Something like 
SELECT * FROM .... 
OR 
SELECT * FROM ....

Comment: like select *
  from clients
 where name like '%name%'
    or Company like '%name%'
    or Address like '%name%'
    or CompanyId like '%name%'
    or InvoiceAddress like '%name%'

Comment: Thank you for suggesition.I appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice to use * in application code on production environment its always good to name the columns rather than using *.

If you are not using like then you can combine all the where statements into a single where clause

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 'name' in (name, number)....;
```

Comment: Since I have more then 20 columns and It kill me to write 20 column in `SELECT` statment  :D 
But however I accept you answer and you are right 100%.

Comment: If you using SQL developer you can simply drag table name and it will give you the option to select all columns with name :)

Answer (score 0):

- When you are using union you don't need to use semicolon(;)
  after every select statement
- Using Like in oracle function and procedure we have to use
  concatination as  like '%'||name||'%'